# how to add a table comment in laravel migration

Tags: php, laravel, migration

[image]
[image]

How can i add a comment Like this Comment.
my Code:

```
$table->string('stock_type');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$table->string('field')->comment('some comment');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$table->string('stock_type')->comment('this is comment');
```